# PHP on IIS - access denied error

Tags: php, windows, iis

I get an `access denied` error while executing any PHP file. I'm running php on windows and IIS 7. It doesn't seem to be a iis error because it just show a blank page containing the error.

What may cause this problem?

Comment: It could be a permissions issue...have you tried running things as an administrator?

Comment: I set the permissions for all users to full control, for both php-cgi and my php file.Is there anything else to do?

Answer (score 0):

Please check if the php files are encrypted. If so, please go into Properties > Advanced and uncheck Encrypt content to secure data and try running them again.